# Hibernate - map a row to either of two subclasses

Tags: spring, hibernate, inheritance

I have a Superclass

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "entity_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Table(name = "my_super")
public abstract class MySuper{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "super_id")
    private Long id;
}
```

and two subclasses

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("sub1")
public class Sub1 extends MySuper {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("sub2")
public class Sub2 extends MySuper {}
```

Now if another class has both of these subclasses in it, is it possible to instantiate one of them through the same join table - same row ??

For instance:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "caller")
public class Caller{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "caller_id")
    Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "caller_super", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "caller_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "super_id"))

    private Set<Sub1> sub1s;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "caller_super", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "caller_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "super_id"))
    Sub2 sub2;
}
```

I keep getting this error when trying to instantiate a Caller Object:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of my.test.Caller.sub2; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of my.test.Caller.sub2
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:679)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:102)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:368)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)

nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this two line shouldnt be same

```
@JoinTable(name = "caller_super", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "caller_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "super_id"))
private Set<Sub1> sub1s;
```

--

```
@JoinTable(name = "caller_super", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "caller_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "super_id"))
private Sub2 sub2;
```

because they are not same entity and their join table should be different. For `ManyToMany` relationship type is `Sub1` but if you try to put them same table hibernate will try to put `Sub2` to `sub1s` . But it is not vaild. Try to change your join table. For `ManyToOne` relationship.